# jQuery Inconsistent text() val() selection and populating input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

`$name` and `$id` are only copied properly a small portion of the time. Selection is expected to populate the input `#user_search` but selections come up undefined. The text is copied properly at what seems like random...

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="user" id="user_search" autocomplete="off" 
class="user_live form-control" data-parsley-required="true" value="" />
<div id="user_result"></div>
```

HTML Added to DOM

```
<div id="user_result" style="display: block;">      
    <div class="showResult row">
        <div class="box-body">
            <a class="user_id" id="353">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                    <img height="50px" src="/assets/user_1.jpg">            
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-xs-9">
                    <span class="name">First Last</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="showResult row">
        <div class="box-body">
            <a class="user_id" id="200">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                    <img height="50px" src="/assets/user_2.jpg">            
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-xs-9">
                    <span class="name">First Last</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#user_result').on('click',function(e){ 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    var $name = $clicked.find('.name').text(); //removed .html($name)
    alert($name);
    $('#user_search').val($name);
});
```

Comment: What do you expect `.html($name)` to do?

Comment: I've removed since it's not needed, but results are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies with `e.target` and `.find()` not working quite right with that layout. Try this:

```
$('#user_result').on('click',function(e){ 
    var $name  = $(e.target).closest('.showResult').find('.name').text();
    alert($name);
    $('#user_search').val($name);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/feab9ms0/

Answer (score 1):

When the click event is triggered, the actual target is the `img` tag and not the `div` itself. Since the element with class `.name` is not contained in the `img`, you do not get any matching results back. Therefore you need to use the `.closest` to navigate to the least parent tag which contains the `img` tag.

```
$("#user_result").on("click",function(e){ 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    var $name = $clicked.closest(".box-body").find('.name').text();
    alert($name);
    $('#user_search').val($name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialize the `$name` before assigning to here `html($name).text()`,
which is causing t render the decision as undefined.

Comment: Good catch. It's not even needed. So which that removed it is still working just the same

Comment: why are you binding click event on the div id "user_result" ?